# Transiend Exception NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I have 3 tables:

Employee {PK: EmployeeId, name, lastname}
Project {PK: ProjectId, name, description}

EmployeebyProject {**PK:EmployeeId** :int, **PK:ProjectId** :Project, DateBegin :int, DateEnd : DateTime}

I need make some CRUD's in this table.

for now I need Insert, by the way in the software in nhibernate the class EmployeebyProject have the object Employee and Project instead of EmployeeId and ProjectId.

This is the mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="AdminProject"
                   namespace="AdminProject.Business.Entity">

  <class name="EmployeebyProject">

    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="Employee" column="EmployeeId"  class="Employee"></key-many-to-one>
      <key-many-to-one name="Project" column="ProjectId"  class="Project" ></key-many-to-one>
    </composite-id>


    <property name="DateBegin"/>
    <property name="DateEnd"/>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem is when I try to save occurs the NHibernate.TransientObjectException. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

A TransientObjectException means that you've told Hibernate to save some object, but that object references another object which you haven't saved. There are generally two ways to fix that:

1. Manually save the other object before the enclosing transaction is committed.
2. Add [cascading](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades) to the relationship so that when you save the first object, the other object is saved, too, just be being referenced from the first one.

Comment: so, in the case of add cascading, in this mapping, how is the sintax? Thanks

Comment: @ale: I'm not certain since it's part of a composite-id, but I suspect you can just add `cascade="..."` with whatever [cascade type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive) you want.